# Replace a fragment or add fragment just once and then show/hide it. Efficient?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, fragmenttransaction, fragmentmanager

I am looking for a better approach here. What you suggest if i have 10+ fragments on a navigation drawer.

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager ();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction ();
```

Using singleton pattern to get the instance of a fragment and add just once to fragmentTransaction if it's not added.

```
fragmentTransaction.add (R.id.testLayoutContent, fragment);
```

Or the another approach which initialize fragment each time and replace the fragment.

NOTE: Each fragments have customize components, live map etc.

Comment: You should consider that using a Singleton you keep all the created fragments in memory, which i don't think to be a good thing. Especially with heavy contents

Comment: Yes but loading fragment every time and replacing it causing crash.

Comment: Because before to recreate the fragment you should check if it is saved in the fragmentmanager and if so reuse it.